# "Forbidden" icon appears instead of language icon in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, language-support

Hi I am relatively newbie in ubuntu and I am using Trusty 64bits. The input language indicator instead of showing the active input language, displays the forbidden sign, see the snapshot below. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What does clicking on that indicator do?

Comment: It shows me the available input languages, e.g. `En`, `Gr` etc.

Comment: System Settings → Text Entry → Lower left corner: [v] Show current input source in the menu bar. First hide it then logout and then log back in and again show it. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: If it doesn't the type this command - "restart unity-panel-service"

Comment: Yes! The first tip through the `System Settings` worked! I had seen the tick but I didn't realize that I had to log out and relogin to fix ;). Thank you. You can write it as an answer for me to upvote if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Goto System Settings → Text Entry → Lower left corner: [v] Show current input source in the menu bar. First hide it then logout and then log back in and again show it.
2. If it doesn't then type this command -

> restart unity-panel-service

Glad! that the first tip worked for you. Wrote the 2nd for if it comes in handy to somebody else.